# How to extend RouterOutlet of Angular 2 RC 4 for Athentication

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have tried the CanActivate (Angular Documentation) and it works. Since I have to add that to every route in need security, I wanted to extend the RouterOutlet and check for authentication before a route is made.

```
import {Directive, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ResolvedReflectiveProvider} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router/src/router';
import {RouterOutletMap} from '@angular/router/src/router_outlet_map';
import {RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router/src/router_state';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class SecuredRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {

    constructor(outletMap: RouterOutletMap,
              location: ViewContainerRef,
              componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              name: string) {

        super(outletMap, location, componentFactoryResolver, name);
    } 

    activate(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, providers: ResolvedReflectiveProvider[], outletMap: RouterOutletMap) {
          /* TODO : Check for authentication */
          return super.activate(activatedRoute, providers, outletMap);
    }
}
```

I get an error ***Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.*** for the super() method in the constructor.
Is this the proper way to extend a RouterOutlet..? Please Help.. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In RC4 it is suggested that instead of implementing RouterOutlet, you implement the class CanActivate.

See [this link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard) to the Angular 2 documentation to see how to do so.

You just need to return a boolean of whether the user is allowed through or not, and then put a reference to that class in your routes (assuming you're using the new component router).